# Best separators for string split

Tags: java, string, split, separator

I am working on an app that uses GCM. I would like to send some information through a push notification to my app that includes text and numbers generated by the user. These information I would like to split up so I can update a database. 
My issue and/or question is what is best separator to use to split up this string? I would like to take into account the user may use such a separator (by accident) and as such the string split is useless. What do you think is the best way to approach this?

UPDATE:

Thanks @assylias, who is right in the context of GCM and JSON. Still would be interesting to know what other people use as string separators.

Comment: CSV ? Where each data is a quoted value like "xyz,10","abc" etc ..

Comment: Encode the data to base64

Comment: Don't invent your own serialization format. Use one of the zillions that are out there and have been well tested, with serialization/deserialization code in lots of languages. JSON is a popular choice, as is Google protobuf.

Comment: The String split may actually be your solution. You can use ~ or ^ as seperators.

Comment: You can use a character that the user cannot enter. A null (`'\0'`) works well; if nulls in a string can cause problems, sometimes a tab can do the trick.

Comment: GCM already uses JSON - just create one field per information in your JSON document.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably make up your own string delimiter. It could be anything. something like "#^!"

and use the StringTokenizer to parse your input using your delimiter.

Comment: GCM uses JSON, there is no need to use a custom separator.

Comment: You _could_ do this, but then you have to worry about users who type in "#^!" as their input. At best you'll get weird bugs, and at worst it could be an injection attack. The problem of serializing structured data has already been solved -- use one of those solutions. If GCM uses JSON, that's a natural choice.